# Restricting file size for an Assets Volume

Tags: assets, limit

I have a use case where I want to limit the allowed file size for a certain Assets Volume to 20kb. All other volumes should be allowed files no matter the size.

I have looked at some other threads already that suggest developing a plugin to do this, or use the Yii event system for file uploads.

I have made other simple plugins before that interacted with entries, but I cannot understand how to make a plugin that latches onto the file uploading event.

Does anyone have any good documentation for where to begin with this? It is version 3.0

Answer (score 2):

There's no way for the moment to limit filesize by Volume, but your can create a custom module with the `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE` hooked on Assets.

Here's a [related post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23261/how-to-set-different-file-size-upload-limits-for-different-asset-sources).

Comment: 'Limit' for Craft fields refers to the maximum number of files that can be assigned to a field, not the file size (or total file size) of those files.

Comment: Not enough coffee this morning -_-